# Twitter - "Main page" button doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: twitter, google-chrome

I started to use **Twitter** (on their official website) a month ago and everything worked fine.

But yesterday the **"Main page/Home" button** stopped working.

I just read through some tweets - I scrolled down with my mouse. When I wanted to return to the top, I used to click the Home button and it scrolled up.

But now, It scrolls up (I'd say) 1 pixel and nothing more (in other words - I would have to click the Home button thousands times to get to the top of the page).

I use **Google Chrome**.

What have I **tried**:

- Logout and login again
- Restart Chrome
- Delete Twitter-related cookies
- Delete Chrome cache
- Login to Twitter in Chrome anonymous mode

None of these helped

Then I tried to login to Twitter in **Internet Explorer** and the button **worked**

Please help me to get this back to work. I don't want to switch to services like TweetDeck. I just want to continue with that "old and good" Twitter.
Thanks

Comment: Try disabling each/every extension you have installed in your browser.

Comment: @Alex didn't help. And I have also tried it yet - the Google Chrome anonymous mode disables every extensions, doesn't use or save cookies and doesn't save history.

Comment: @Kazarp What version and channel of Chrome do you have?

Comment: @Julio Version 39.0.2171.65 m, stable for Windows 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are zoomed out and viewing the page at 100%. This happened to me as well and it was simply because I was viewing the web page at 110%.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I was viewing in 125%. Now it works 

Answer (score 0):

Click F12 and open debug mode in browser and check whether you are getting any error message. Also check whether java script is disabled in the browser.